# Member function that takes a function as argument: Why does the compiler chose the const overload when passing a lambda with auto& argument

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a class that wraps different types of containers/views and can invoke functions on all elements with a `forEach` member function. There are different overloads of the `forEach` function which differ by their constraints on the function type (which is a template) and their constness. Now I noticed that when called on a non-const instance which a lambda that has an `auto&` parameter the compiler wrongly choses the const overload which then fails to compile. Below is a stripped down example that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>
#include <span>

template <class, class>
struct FunctionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible : std::false_type {};

template <class Fn, class Ret, class... Args>
struct FunctionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible<Fn, Ret (Args...)>
{
    static constexpr bool value = requires (Fn&& t, Args&&... args) { { t (args...) } -> std::convertible_to<Ret>; };
};

template <class Fn, class Signature>
concept functionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible = FunctionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible<Fn, Signature>::value;

template <class T>
struct Foo
{
    using ValueType = typename T::value_type;
    T& vec;

    Foo (T& src) : vec (src) {}

    template <functionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible<void (ValueType&)> Fn>
    void forEach (Fn&& fn)
    {
        for (auto& e : vec)
            fn (e);
    }

    template <functionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible<void (const ValueType&)> Fn>
    void forEach (Fn&& fn) const
    {
        for (auto& e : vec)
            fn (e);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> v { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f };
    std::span s (v);

    Foo a (v);
    Foo b (s);

    a.forEach ([] (auto& e) { e *= 2.0f; }); // -> error: cannot assign to variable 'e' with const-qualified type 'const float &'
    a.forEach ([] (float& e) { e *= 2.0f; });

    b.forEach ([] (auto& e) { e *= 2.0f; }); // -> error: cannot assign to variable 'e' with const-qualified type 'const float &'
    a.forEach ([] (float& e) { e *= 2.0f; });
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwAcpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgAMwA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/kEZWY4CYRHRLHEJKbaY9qUMQgRMxAR5Pn6BdQ05za0E5VGx8UmpCi1tHQXdEwNDldVjAJS2qF7EyOwcJhoAguaJ4cjeWADUJoluBACeaZgA%2BgTETIQKl9i7B2ZHDCde50ubjQf0waQI70Sn32h2Op0wFyuADdMA4SB8vrC/vDEW4FGlDBiYfsCJgWGkDKTcScmAoFKQzjS6US9hNiF4HGcAGJeP6NADqhAQQjwwGYBA2mAA8sQAJLk2h4ZCEWg3DwMFFtPAxehnEBnCboEAgKhiJRPO4IkzJKzJAAilysxL2pIVTCpQKZCm5DAZXrOACVMAQ/QY6QA6SNnPbEYCQ6Gs54cgjc3kOHKCgjC0XiyUy%2BUUpUqtUCTWOHWYIFc32B4NnCAxuOR8PLFnWp17M5dg0tRzIRkCCaYVRpYhnGKoTxnJFiLxWxJ2s7ETAARy8eGX3og1fMADY92cQ9HY%2B8zPuz82zq048sLja7xZD/Xrwpm7frYuALQfHtGlCl%2BJy3oJ5UCBIMCAxRJHw/R1MXtWDnVdCl3XnYEw29atQ1pb0RTFd1JRZEEtnBM4qDTAUhVw3Nl3zBUiwIVV1TLbVdUuRceT5DNKJzfCaLlOjlQYksNUAljKyuTCzio3jxOwY0Z28cSOy%2BJDKVQ/0ABUWTZZNuUnOCO27M4vCyIwzgANVnTANMtRFF1ue5mDYM4NPkqyLXuBDO27LSz2nVEvK%2BIyuUnetfN3A1NlvfUUX7CAFCih8YOdIzVJQ3EyM4gRM2zPCJT4gtFUExiAK1CsgSRVA8HQetLMUmzPLPVsoR9FkjMq6rSJIbAmGQBB6x3M8DyoBhW32Iz2yCozu34McICYLwiAPBEYtRMbvOm6aRvrTBmsM7tkoOcbuzSj0rky9Nsu4vK834wtiuE5jyuRKqaogEEJgsqyGsrJqfx3KEpq7Dqatmnq%2BoGhg92G0aBwYCYgaS47Ntm59FtAvyVv85B1s2lGGB2vbEcOmCoMxfZwhTFhXgYCB1sm5Hf3k1EiGIIEqFoVB3R/JEHzOLhww0KgGTMQXhbORIxYZSQxbvB0ycZw1jXxQwDXrJEiZS7sQtQK91c1ja9N1mJ6wUA3EaYcMwd6/qIBMABWKx7cXeb0eW997wRAAqNizlFoXHTlvazgAehDs5vxa%2BJiBIfVRAYBhUBTbCc0PXWZ2IPAmArM4wA4TA87OAB3IU4YmT81zEPAaEwGqHIRPOPpTDmuZTPc84tq3upt%2BsHadl2W%2B5zGPcfb3ff9qhA4/c3GZiLviHB22%2B4dl2FqW4e%2BbHhc/bFqf7WDsOI5/aPY8ZQxE%2BTulU6IadWiznO84Ljhi9LpuK68Kua7r2zG8HZvOfdBcM8HdGaW2thDO2jsV71kHhBDe7Yzhb0XBPPedoDYTUZsufKBMNCBXtBwVYtBOD214H4DgWhSCoE4G4aw1gDTrE2FaH4PBSAEE0AQ1YABrEA9t7bhkSFwLgiReECKESI/QnBJCkPYZQzgvAFAgA0Kw9hqw4CwCQMOVE6MyAUHmieZQhh6hCAQKgIuZCWFoHJHQd0OQDERFoMY0xZCKGWLSHQUYNIjBcHthoJRrj3HEEiKwbYvB/H0GIFKRajizEyM0cgRsCiOC8Dic0fAZDeD8EECIMQ7ApAyEEIoFQ6hyE6D0AYIwKBaGWH0NqBRkBVioHBDkRJn5DRsVMJYawZgKEKAYVsPQhpwh2KMSYmJ3BeDPEwNsFhRcXhpE4DwQhxDpElNkRwbAqgtGszOKoAIu5Py7kkIycpwB%2BZ8I0ILesNDOnVLOLgQgJAgECOWBMlRqwECYCYFgBIdNSDcMkDLXcAQ9kAqBSCyQQLdwSI4FI0gLAJC%2BNIM43gVCkm2EUcokpywlkcDMCsihqLXlYtWJqLIzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D) is the live example on Compiler Explorer.

Now my questions are: Why does it pick the const overload in case of `auto&`? And what can I do to make the compiler pick the non-const overload in this case?

Comment: Because your lambda is not constrained, `auto&` can be instantiated as a `const T&`, so the constraint is satisfied making the lambda body cause a hard error. Try `[] (auto& e) requires requires { e *= 2.0f; } { e *= 2.0f; }`.

Comment: Pro-tip: you can specialize [variable templates](https://godbolt.org/z/6hjPK33j6)

Comment: This is indeed a nice tip @Barry. Was not aware of that, will definitively use that in future

Comment: @康桓瑋 is `requires requires` a typo? Shouldn't it just be one `requires`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not a typo, it’s necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When checking the concept `functionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible<(closure type), void (const ValueType&)>` during overload resolution, it has to instantiate the body of the lambda with the auto parameter deduced as `const float` to figure out what the auto return type is.

This is not a SFINAE context, so `const float& e` `e *= 2.0f` is a hard error. This is happening before a `forEach` function is chosen.

It goes away if you make it SFINAE-able or remove the auto return type:

```cpp
a.forEach ([] (auto& e) -> decltype(e*=2.0f, void()) { e *= 2.0f; });
// functionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible<(closure type), void (const ValueType&)>
// will be false

a.forEach ([] (auto& e) -> void { e *= 2.0f; });
// functionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible<(closure type), void (const ValueType&)>
// will be true, but the non-const forEach overload will be picked anyways
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to concepts still, and your first suggestion (`decltype`) is throwing me. I understand that the error is occurring due to the compiler attempting to determine the `auto` return types, and facing a typical `const` violation. The closest I'm getting is that you're providing hints to the concept, but I don't know if I'm right or not. Could you break down that first suggestion a bit more?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I understand the problem. Still I wonder if there is any option to make the compiler ignore the `FunctionWithSignatureOrImplicitlyConvertible` template specialisation in an SFINAE way in case a lambda cannot be instantiated with the given parameter set? I tried to add a `requires std::invocable<Fn, Args...>` to the specialisation but that fails as well.